Migrate Express Backend and React Native Frontend to Monorepo for TRPC
I have a node.js Express (Typescript) backend. I also have a React Native frontend. These exist in separate repos.
I want to use TRPC: https://trpc.io/ to achieve end to end type safety. To my understanding, this (generally) requires a monorepo setup.
How can I migrate my current setup to a monorepo? Can I just create one parent folder, with it's own package.json just for TRPC? And that parent folder contains both the frontend and backend code? Are there different considerations for when I need to deploy? Or no because they will only ever import types from the shared code?
I don't want to deal with monorepo tools like nx or turborepo, unless it makes something easier for me. I don't believe I have any need for a monorepo besides this specific use case.
I also would like to avoid keeping the repos separate and using a shared NPM package as that seems complicated.
